# Can I get dictionary from pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a following question. I would like to get content of a table in dictionary format. My code:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser

import pymysql as mysql

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read("config.ini")
        user = config["db"]["user"]
        passwd = config["db"]["password"]
        host = config["db"]["host"]
        db = config["db"]["database"]

        self.connection = mysql.connect(
            user=user,
            passwd=passwd,
            host=host,
            db=db,
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def init_dict(self):
       
        query = """
                SELECT a, b
                FROM mytable
                """
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return dict(data)
```

Is there a more pythonic way how to get `data` in the method `init_dict` as a dictionary? I found, that it should be possible to return a `dict` directly from the cursor, but I don`t know how. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(cursor=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)`?

Comment: @Wondercricket thanks. So I have to to modify the __init__ ? Or is it possible in the init_idict method, too? Can you answer it and show me the whole code, please?

Comment: Before I post an answer, please post your expected/desired output. By adding the DictCursor to the cursor, `init_dict` will return a list of dicts. In your current code, `init_dict` will return a `dict` with `a` and `b` as the key/value. Which one are you wanting?

Comment: @Wondercricket Expected output is a `dict` with a and b as a key/value. Thanks